# Is it possible to add a string with spaces or special characters to an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Is it possible to add a string with spaces or special characters to an enum?

For example, I have a string `Insurance KR Users (Name)`, I have tried to include this string into an enum:

```
    public enum MemberGroup
    {
        Insurance KR Users (Name)
    }
```

but it throws an error.

How can I include these types of strings into enum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The enum members itself must be a [valid identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx), so it can't contain spaces or special characters.

But you could use the `DescriptionAttribute` to provide a more complete description of each enum value:

```
public enum MemberGroup
{
    [Description("Insurance KR Users (Name)")]
    InsuranceKrUsers_Name
}
```

To retrieve the description, use something like this:

```
public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
{
   FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()); 
   DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = 
     (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
     typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
   return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For me Discription attribute could not be find by the compiler. Is it available in .net 3.5. Pls help me if any other to remember.

Comment: It's there, just make sure to use the  System.ComponentModel namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The enum itself can't contain spaces, and as Peter says, it can only contain a certain set of characters.

You could use the enum's Description attribute however to store some extra information, but this would have to be retrieved using reflection. There are quite a few examples over the internet how to do it, but just as an example, [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/01/19/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum.aspx) is one.