# How to declare special characters and spaces in enumerations

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enumeration as below

```
private enum gettype
{
    Xml/adf = 1,
    xml/adf and html = 2
};
```

but as of my knowledge I know that we could not declare special characters spaces in between.
I even tried "display" and "description" though didn't work.
So does any one know any work around.

Comment: Do you want to use the enum as a string at some point?  In that case, you could always write a custom parser that removes `_` and adds blank lines in its place.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Enum members must be valid C# identifiers. You can decorate them with a variety of attributes, however:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

private enum gettype
{
    [Description("Xml/adf")]
    XmlAdf = 1,

    [Description("Xml/adf and html")]
    XmlAdfAndHtml = 2
}
```

Now to convert the enum value to a description string, or vice versa you'd have to use reflection, one way or other. For example:

```
var enumValue = gettype.XmlAdfAndHtml;
var attr = (DescriptionAttribute[])
        typeof(gettype).GetField(enumValue.ToString())
                       .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
var stringValue = attr[0].Description; // Xml/adf and html
```

Comment: as I mentioned earlier i had used description it didn't work, it says "Attribute not valid on declaration type"

Comment: @user2530398 The [System.ComoponentModel.DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) does work since it has `AttributeTargets.All`. I've tried it out myself just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Refers the below stack overflow links which may helpful to you.

[Is it possible to add a string with spaces or specialcharacters to an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735428/is-it-possible-to-add-a-string-with-spaces-or-specialcharacters-to-an-enum)

[How can I use a special char in a C# enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373986/how-can-i-use-a-special-char-in-a-c-sharp-enum)